# Правильно ли без тире перед "это"?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, разговорная-речь

> — "Пятибалльный" пишется с двумя Л? Не знал.
>   — Конечно! **Бальные это** танцы, например.

Вот такой диалог в разговорном стиле, то есть с упрощённым выражением своих мыслей.  *Танцы* не определяют слово *бальные* в классическом смысле, когда оба слова выражены одной частью речи. Можно перефразировать: *Бальными **бывают** танцы, например.* Так и правильнее сказать, но часто заменяют на *это* в простой речи.

Мне ***не хочется*** ставить *тире* перед *это,* однако один человек считает, что оно необходимо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструкция разговорного типа, но **тире надо ставить**.

1) Почему не хочется? Сравним: *Бывают, например, бальные танцы*.

Или: *Это, например, бальные танцы.*  А теперь применим **инверсию**: *Бальные – это танцы, например.*

При инверсии **тире ставится** по правилам. Структура меняется, а без тире и паузы смысл предложения может быть не понят.

2) Другой вариант объяснения – это **номинатив в препозиции.** *Бальные* — это танцы, например.

Номинатив только **задает тему** (мы хотим обозначить область применения прилагательного *бальные*), там нет жесткой грамматической связи. А тире в таких предложениях ставится.

Comment: Спасибо! А зачем в 3-й строчке запятая после "это"?

Comment: Ну Тёмыч, ну опечатка же, ну понятно же.

Comment: Артем, я не знаю, взялась ниоткуда. Я точно помню, что не собиралась ее ставить.   Это мистическая такая запятая, из другого измерения.

Comment: А почему "*не понят*" раздельно? Может быть каков? Непонят. https://kakpishu.ru/как-пишется-слово/непонят

Comment: Откуда вы только берете такие ссылки, а бы на них ставила  пометку 18+. То  есть не рекомендуется для посещения людям, не имеющих устойчивых грамматических навыков (это шутка, чур, не обижаться). Правильность написания гарантирую.  Почему?  А самим догадаться? Подсказка: зайдите в Нацкорпус, посмотрите частотность вариантов и сделайте правильный вывод. Или на форуме спросите.

Comment: (Ссылка просто из Гугл.) Я не говорил, что это неправильно. Просто интересна ваша аргументация как авторская. Как-то вариант с причастием плохо звучит. "Может быть" указывает на оттенок прилагательного.

Comment: Угнетен, непонят, одинок.  Переход причастия в прилагательное, на что указывает ряд синонимов.

Answer (score 1):

Не хочется не тира, а что-то иное смущает (принятое за нежелание тире), хочется чего-то неназванного... пока.

Дело в том, что "бальные" во второй реплике - это обыгрываемое (передразненное) слово. Его надо закавычить. И "пятибалльный" тоже (в значении "слово").

> — "Пятибалльный" пишется с двумя "л"? Не знал.
>
> — Конечно! "Бальные" — это танцы, например.

Comment: Согласен. Может, *неназванн**ое***?

Comment: Спасибо, Галина! Да, "пятибалльный", конечно, надо закавычить. Я это и имел в виду, поэтому сейчас поставлю.

Answer (score 0):

Знак препинания необходим. Тире ставится перед словами *это, это есть, значит, это значит, вот*, присоединяющими сказуемое к подлежащему (Розенталь)

Comment: «Танцы не определяют слово бальные в классическом смысле.» Артём Луговой так определил проблему.